# Javascript on click apply class to a different class

Tags: javascript

I am a Javascript beginner/weakling and I know I need it here to dynamically apply a class to another element to make it hidden, ie - accordion.

In basic I have the following unordered list:

```
<ul class="category-0">
 <li class="list-0">
  <div class="submenu">
   <p><a href="#list-1">Item One</a><p>
   <p>100</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="category-1">
   <li class="list-1">
    <div class="submenu">
     <p><a href="#list-2">Sub item One</a></p>
     <p>50></p>
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to put an accordion on the List-0 so that when the link is clicked it displays List-1. I have set up .list-1 {display: none;} and .active {display: block !important;}. So right now list 1 is not displaying. In my JavaScript I have:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("list-0");
var i;
for (i = 0; i< acc.length; i++){
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var list = getElementsByClassName("list-1");
    if (list.style.display =="none") {
      list.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      list.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
};
```

When I run this it toggles but only on list-0 not list-1. I've tried variations of trying var list = this.nextElementSibling; as well to see if I'm hitting it correctly. Doesn't seem to work.

So how do I toggle the class of active on list-1?

Comment: Two error here: var list = getElementsByClassName("list-1"); should "var list = document.getElementsByClassName("list-1");" and getElementsByClassName() method return object collection so you should add index before any execution on it so "list.style" should list[index].style

Comment: That is actually exactly what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you change the class to active, you can no longer lookup the elements by class name "list-1" because it is no longer part of that class, here is a fix:

JavaScript

```
function acc1() {
  var subList = document.getElementById("list-1");
  if(subList.classList.contains("invisible")) {
    subList.classList.replace("invisible", "active");
  }
  else {
    subList.classList.replace("active", "invisible");
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.invisible {display: none !important;}
.active {display: block !important;}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <ul class="category-0">
 <li class="list-0">
  <div class="submenu">
   <p><a href="#list-1" onclick="acc1()">Item One</a><p>
   <p>100</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="category-1">
   <li id="list-1" class="invisible">
    <div class="submenu">
     <p><a href="#list-2">Sub item One</a></p>
     <p>50></p>
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```